# Corona SDK Vungle ads error

Tags: lua, callback, coronasdk, ads

I am working on an app that I am monetizing with Vungle and when I call ads.init, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Corona Runtime Error
---------------------------
?:0: attempt to concatenate a table value
stack traceback:
    ?: in function 'providerNameToModuleName'
    ?: in function 'requireProvider'
    ?: in function 'setCurrentProvider'
    ?: in function 'init'
    scripts\game.lua:7: in function 'new'
    main.lua:3: in main chunk
```

Here is the code calling ads.init:

```
local game = {}
local gameMetaTable = {__index = game}

function game.new ()
 local newGame = {}
 newGame.ads = require ("ads")
 newGame.ads:init ("vungle", "--[[my app ID here]]", function () game:adcallback () end)

 return setmetatable (newGame, gameMetaTable)
end

function game:adcallback ()
 -- do stuff with the ad in here
end

return game
```

In light of all this, my question is really this:  How do I properly initialize Vungle ads with Corona SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

newGame.ads.init ("vungle", "--[[my app ID here]]", game:adcallback )

When you use the : operator, the first parameter is the object itself. ads.init() expects a string as the first parameter, not a table (i.e. object). You need to call it with the . separator.

Finally the callback parameter needs to be the address of the callback function. You were creating an anonymous function that called your adcallback function, but with out the needed "event" table.

Rob